# leaflet.js setView() & map.on("zoomend") cyclic call

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I use angularjs and leaflet.js.

In my controller I set a listener on the leaflet map zoom :

```
map.on("zoomend", function () {
    refreshData(...); // use the zoom & bound to get data.
});
```

The *refreshData()* refresh the markers displayed in the map according to many criteria ( facets ) and re adjust the map with *setView()*. ( *refreshData()* can also be called by other function )

```
var refreshData = function(){
    // lot of thinks...
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon),zoomlevel);
}
```

So when *refreshData* is called i want to disable the *map.on("zoomend")* listener because it make a cyclic call.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a flag variable.

```
map.on("zoomend", refreshData);

var refreshData = function(){
    map.off("zoomend");
    // lot of thinks...
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon),zoomlevel);
    map.on("zoomend", refreshData);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. this can't work for me because i need to call refreshdata when i zoom.

Comment: I tried to make this but don't work : *var refreshData = function(){ map.on("zoomend", function () {}); map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon),zoomlevel); ... }*

Comment: thanks i was searching since 3 hours. map.off() is what i need

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pk. for the answer. 
I had to add a timeout to make it work properly because the *map.on("zoomend", refreshData);* is called just after the call of *map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon),zoomlevel);* who take some times to finish :

```
var refreshData = function(){
    map.off("zoomend");
    // lot of thinks...
    map.setView(new L.LatLng(lat,lon),zoomlevel);
    $timeout(function () {
        map.on("zoomend", refreshData);
    },3000);
}
```

the best way will be with a callback on *setView* but I don't find a way to do something like this :

```
var refreshData = function(){
    map.off("zoomend");
    // lot of thinks...
    map.setView(
        new L.LatLng(latlon["lat"], latlon["lon"]),
        GeographieService.getZoomFromLocalisationtype("continents"), 
        {'reset' : true }
    ).then(function (data) {
        map.on("zoomend", refreshData);
    });
}
```

any idea ?